# I am working on a rails web application i have added views and respectively css files, the css styling is displayed but not correctly

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

i have added views their respective stylesheets in the stylesheets tag. I have precompiled the css files, when the server is run the css styling is displayed, the problem is it is not displayed correctly, when the same css and html file is singularly  displayed it functions properly but it is not displayed correctly in the rails app

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more information in order to get help, eg: is this in development mode? Where have you put your CSS files? What does your layout file look like? etc.

Comment: When you inspect the view, are your styles getting applied?  The above comment is on point, you will need to provide some more information, right now there is just way too many possibilities to what an issue could be to give any help.

Comment: okay i will edit the question add some screenshots